# copy data of particular id from one table and paste at particular id of another table

Tags: mysql

I have a problem: I have to tables `examp1` and `examp2`. I want to copy data of `examp1` whose `id=138` and paste that into another table `examp2` at `id=5`. I tried this

```
insert into examp1 (rates,publishPrice,name) 
 select rates,publishPrice,name from examp2 where id=138;
```

and

```
insert into examp1 (rates,publishPrice,name) where id=5 
 select rates,publishPrice,name from examp2 where id=138;`
```

but I am getting problem in 2nd query. While in 1st query the data of id=138 is copied but not at particular id.

Comment: This question is very confusing because you mention ids `1` and `5` in the text, but have `138` in the sample SQL.  Plus you say you want data in `examp2` but are inserting into `examp1` in the sample SQL.  I am trusting the text.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited my question. Now I hope its clear to you. Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

If the id with `5` does not exist in `examp1`, perhaps you want:

```
insert into examp2(id, rates, publishPrice, name)
    select 5, rates, publishPrice, name
    from examp1
    where id = 138;
```

If the ids both exist, then you want an update:

```
update examp2 cross join
       (select e1.*
        from examp1 e1
        where id = 138
       ) e1
       on examp2.id = 5 
     set e2.rates = e1.rates,
         e2.publishPrice = e1.publishPrice,
         e2.name = e1.name;
```

Or something like this, based on what your question really is.

Comment: I have to copy that data at existing id.